# matlab and simulink

Tags: matlab, variables, each, simulink

hi I am trying to build a simulink model for canny edge detection . I am not getting how to implement non maximal suppression block in simulink. Is it possible to create a block by writing mat-lab code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called embedded matlab function. I think it is under user-defined blocks

Answer (score 0):

To create user defined block you can use S functions in Simulink.
You can write this S function either using Matlab or C/C++ that depends on your requirement.

Refer this link

http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/s-function-basics.html